# ¿Cómo combinar array de objetos a uno solo?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js

Tengo un Componente en Vue, donde traigo un array llamado `arrayTareas2`(Ver código) proveniente de una consulta en mi base de datos, y tengo un array fijo llamado `arrayTareas1` de valores fijos.

Si ejecutan, pueden notar que el resultado que me entrega al ejecutar el push, es enviarme el array de objeto, dentro de otro array de objeto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    arrayTareas1:[ 
    {text:'tarea1'},
    {text:'tarea2'},   //ARRAY FIJO
    {text:'tarea3'}],
    
    arrayTareas2: [
    {text:'tarea4'},  //ARRAY PROVENIENTE DE LA BASE DE DATOS
    {text:'tarea5'}]
  },
    methods: {
    click(){  
    this.arrayTareas1.push(this.arrayTareas2)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
{{arrayTareas1}}
<br>
<button @click="click()">agregar</button>
  <br>
</div>
```

Y lo que me gustaría es poder realizar un merge, de combinar ambos datos dentro de un sólo array de objeto, es decir, que quede sólo en `arrayTareas1`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Para esto fue creado el método concat (): https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el operator de spread:

`...`

De [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) en español:

> La sintaxis extendida o spread syntax permite a un elemento iterable
> tal como un arreglo o cadena ser expandido en lugares donde cero o más
> argumentos (para llamadas de  función) o elementos (para Array
> literales) son esperados, o a un objeto ser expandido en lugares donde
> cero o más pares de valores clave (para literales Tipo Objeto) son
> esperados.

```js
vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    arrayTareas1:[ 
    {text:'tarea1'},
    {text:'tarea2'},   //ARRAY FIJO
    {text:'tarea3'}],
    
    arrayTareas2: [
    {text:'tarea4'},  //ARRAY PROVENIENTE DE LA BASE DE DATOS
    {text:'tarea5'}]
  },
    methods: {
    click(){  
    this.arrayTareas1.push(...this.arrayTareas2)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
{{arrayTareas1}}
<br>
<button @click="click()">agregar</button>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Genial, era lo que necesitaba. Gracias!